# Atmel studio stimulation

Tags: atmelstudio

I installed `Microchip Studio 7.0.2542` on 2 different PCs. (Formerly known as Atmel Studio.) The version of the `Installed Packages: Atmel Kits - 7.0.132` is identical on both PCs.

The simulator supports a stimulus feature, i.e. you can stimulate the simulated controller with inputs. For that purposes the Debug menu has the items

- Execute Stimulifile
- Set Stimulifile

But this is not available on the second PC.

Is there any option to set or an optional package to install to enable the stimulus feature?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The stimulus functions are only available in the Advanced user interface profile.

The profile is enabled with the menu `Tools->Select profile`.